# Write browser plugin for a personal web application

Tags: plugins

I want to make a browser plugin, similar to that are available for Twitter. But in my case, the users must be able to submit tweets to my web application.

I want to know which language is used to write such plugins.

Comment: Why would anyone need a plugin for Twitter?

Comment: @NSD perhaps you want to read 2 words before what you read - "similar to (plugins which) are available for Twitter."

Comment: Perhaps you want to try that sentence again in English

Comment: It should be noted that what you want is not a plugin, but an extension.

Answer (score 1):

For ie:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/ietoolbartutorial.aspx

For Firefox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension

Good luck :-)

Comment: Is there anything other than C++?

Comment: For internet explorer or firefox?