# Building Plug-in for Android's default browser or Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-widget, google-chrome-extension

Is this possible?

There is very little documentation available and the one useful post I have found has an expired link.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The two plugin systems are completely different. Chrome extensions are far more mature and developer friendly. Bottom line is you'd need to write two different plugins.

Possibly useful links:

- SO post about developing [Android browser plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960050/how-to-develop-plugins-for-the-native-android-browser)
- Getting started with [Chrome extension development](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html)

Comment: Find your answer a little misleading, you can't develop an extension for Chrome for Android.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question has been discussed and answered in following QA :

[How to develop plugins for the native Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960050/how-to-develop-plugins-for-the-native-android-browser)

[Android browser plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150954/android-browser-plugin)

[Write browser plugin for a personal web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611677/write-browser-plugin-for-a-personal-web-application)